# Navigate after login

Tags: react-native

I'm creating an app using React-Native. I added Firebase Auth to my application, but I can't navigate to the Homescreen after log in.
This is my code:

constructor (in LoginScreen):

```
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      email: '',
      password: '',
      status: '',
    }

    this.handlePress = this.handlePress.bind(this)
  }
```

app.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import { AppRegistry } from 'react-native';
import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';

import LoginScreen from './app/screens/LoginScreen';
import RegisterScreen from './app/screens/RegisterScreen';
import HomeScreen from './app/screens/HomeScreen';

const Stylelist = StackNavigator({
  Login: { screen: LoginScreen },
  Register: { screen: RegisterScreen},
  Home: {screen: HomeScreen},
},{headerMode: "none"});

export default Stylelist;
```

handlePress function(function in the Loginscreen):

```
handlePress(){
  firebaseRef.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(this.state.email, this.state.password).then(function(firebaseUser){
    //Success, move to homepage.
    console.log("logged in!")
    navigate("Home")
  }).catch(function(error){
    //Failed to log in, print error.
  });
}
```

This "logged in" does gets printed in the console but won't move to the Homescreen.

this is the render method in the loginScreen.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet, Text, TouchableOpacity, KeyboardAvoidingView, TextInput, StatusBar, Image } from 'react-native';
import { firebaseRef } from '../services/Firebase';

export default class LoginScreen extends Component{

  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      email: '',
      password: '',
      status: '',
    }

    this.handlePress = this.handlePress.bind(this)
  }

  //Trying to login the account with email and password provided by the user.
  handlePress(){
    firebaseRef.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(this.state.email, this.state.password).then(function(firebaseUser){
      //Success, move to homepage.
      console.log("logged in!")
      this.props.navigation.navigate("Home");
    }).catch(function(error){
      //Failed to log in, print error.
    });
  }
  render(){
    const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
    return(
      <KeyboardAvoidingView behavior="padding" style={styles.container}>
      <StatusBar
      barStyle="light-content"
      />
      <View style={styles.logoContainer}>
      <Image
      style={styles.logo}
      source={require('../assets/Logo.png')}/>
      </View>
      <View style={styles.formContainer}>
      <TextInput
      style={styles.txtInput}
      keyboardType="email-address"
      placeholder="email"
      onChangeText={(text)=> this.setState({email: text})}
      placeholderTextColor="#FFFFFF"
      onSumbitEditing={()=>this.passwordInput.focus()}
      returnKeyType="next"
      autoCapitalize="none"
      autoCorrect={false}
      />
      <TextInput
      style={styles.txtInput}
      placeholder="password"
      placeholderTextColor="#FFFFFF"
      onChangeText={(text)=> this.setState({password: text})}
      returnKeyType="go"
      autoCapitalize="none"
      autoCorrect={false}
      secureTextEntry
      ref={(input)=>this.passwordInput = input}
      />
      <TouchableOpacity style={styles.logBtn} onPress={this.handlePress}>
      <Text style={styles.logTxt}>
      Login
      </Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <TouchableOpacity style={styles.regBtn} onPress={()=>navigate("Register")}>
      <Text style={styles.regTxt}>
      create account
      </Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
      </KeyboardAvoidingView>
    );
  }
}
```

I don't get any error printed and the app does not crash, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: could you share the whole component please? It is difficult to diagnose now because of some missing code.

Comment: my bad, I added the relevant code of the render method.

Comment: There might be some error you are not aware, come mistypo, some error in the firebase call. if you log something just before calling to firebase, do you see something? I do believe that sharing the whole component would be beneficial to delp you.

Comment: I added the rest of loginscreen.js I did console.log to see if the handle press working and it is and prints "logged in" when the user is in the firebase.

Comment: hi, can you tell me where did you defined `firebaseUser`? Currently I am facing this same problem but it say error as I did not defined `firebaseUser`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are missing the context inside the promise and `navigate` no longer exists there. So let's pass a parameter navigate callback to make it work:

Firstly, add navigate as a parameter to handlePress

```js
handlePress(navigate){
  firebaseRef.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(this.state.email, this.state.password).then(function(firebaseUser){
    //Success, move to homepage.
    console.log("logged in!")
    navigate("Home");
  }).catch(function(error){
    //Failed to log in, print error.
  });
}
```

Secondly, modify the TouchableOpacity to call handlePress properly:

```html
...
<TouchableOpacity style={styles.logBtn} onPress={() => this.handlePress(navigate)}>
  <Text style={styles.logTxt}>
    Login
  </Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
...
```

Comment: Ok, can you add some log to the reject part? I mean, let's see if there is some error behind

Comment: Here you have something wrong also: `onPress={this.handlePress()}>`. Remove the parenthesis

Comment: I removed the parenthesis, nothing changed. I also tried to log but the app won't crash and won't show any error. like it just ignores the navigation line.

Comment: Do you see any error in the console? Do you see something being logged?

Comment: nothing, only "logged in" that I wrote to see if its getting into the handlePress method.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145227/discussion-between-john-doah-and-facundo-la-rocca).

Comment: Working great. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I know this was resolved but, no resolution was posted here.  If anyone is having issues make sure you can access the navigation prop (try console logging it) another issue may be if you're conditionally rending your navigation stack based if auth exists, that will mean that one stack does not have access to the to other